# HBASE table mapped on Hive, how to get the real table size

Tags: dictionary, hive, hbase

I'm using HBase tables from Hive

for example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `ddid_link_msisdn`(
  `msisdn` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `ddid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe' 
STORED BY 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'hbase.columns.mapping'=':key,fc:ddid', 
  'serialization.format'='1')
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'hbase.table.name'='unifieddata:ddid_link_msisdn_ddid', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1535099920')
```

And anything is fine as usual but...
When I execute `analyse table ddid_link_msisdn compute static` and later ask the table description using `describe extended ddid_link_msisdn` I get:

```
... a lot of info ...etc etc...

{

 totalSize=35566884, 
 numRows=427422, 
 rawDataSize=35139462, 

 COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE=true, numFiles=1, transient_lastDdlTime=1591783620}

... other info ...
```

numRows is exactly the number of the rows, no surprise, totalSize or rawDataSize are about 35Mbytes but if I look the HDFS I see that:

```
   root@mid1-db138hd-12 [10:42am]  ~> hdfs dfs -du -h /hbase/data/unifieddata
   337      1011     /hbase/data/unifieddata/ddid_hub
   265.7 M  797.2 M  /hbase/data/unifieddata/ddid_link_cat_ddid
>> 45.2 M   135.5 M  /hbase/data/unifieddata/ddid_link_msisdn_ddid <---
```

the real size is 45M.

Are there any kindly people can explain to me this extra 28% and, if does it exists, how to get the correct table size from Hive?